# How to create an Ad Rotator

Tags: 7, advertising

In my website, I need to use ad rotator, which have this requirements:

- Allow administrator to manage ads for each page
- Each page may contain different ads
- Administrator may upload more than one ads for each page
- When the user load page, there is only 1 ads will be shown to user and the ads that shown to user may randomly or sequentially load.

For example:

- I have 2 pages, which are page A and B. Then for page A I have 2 ads, which are ads X & Y, and for page B I have 3 ads, which ads ads U, V, & W. When the user load page A, only 1 from 2 ads shown. The ads may randomly or sequentially loaded.
- Let's say, when the first time user load the page, ads Y shown to user, and second time user load the page, ads X shown to user (if ads randomly loaded). Or if the ads sequentially loaded, when the user load page A, then ads X will be shown, after that ads Y, then ads A again, and so on.

My question is:

- Is there any suggestion, which plugin should I use to fulfill my requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [SimpeAds](http://drupal.org/project/simpleads) module

It allows to define ads categories as a separate taxonomy, and then places ads from a given category in a block. Then you can configure the block to display on a page A and to display random one of the ads from a given category.

Comment: how can i configure the block to display the ads randomly, could you explain it? Thanks

Comment: and actually the page where i want to show the ads is a dynamic page. I mean, i use views to display data from content type and configure the data by using contextual filters.

For example:

in my content type, i've content M, which contain field: name, age, address. Then i use views to show specific row of content M in specific page, and I filter the row using field name. So, when i go to page www.domainname.com/A, it will refers to page that contains the details of A and random ads that related with A. Is that possible?